# Jquery & javascript - function result, as property name

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'd like to get an input name, as a property name, using jquery.

The html

```
<input name="data[First][Second]" />
```

The script

```
$.post(
   '/url', 
   {
      $("input").prop("name"): $("input").val()
   }
);
```

how can it be done (directly)?

Comment: It can't. You have to do it in two steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a variable value as a property name in a literal. You have to do it in two steps and to use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) :

```
var obj = {};
obj[$("input").prop("name")] = $("input").val();
$.post('/url', obj);
```

If you don't want to break the flow and you want an expression, you can use a function expression :

```
$.post(
   '/url', (function(){
       var obj = {};
       obj[$("input").prop("name")] = $("input").val();
       return obj;
    })()
);
```

A very slight advantage is also that you don't pollute the external scope with a new variable, but it's usually not clearer.

Comment: I'm sure it's a duplicate, I've seen it, but I can't find it :\

Comment: please check this:   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739870/javascript-auto-execute-anonymous-function-parenthesis

Comment: @yossi You might be interested in this article : http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/