# javascript auto execute anonymous function - parenthesis

Tags: javascript, function

What is - if there is any - the difference between these two pieces of code:

```
(function(){
  // code
});
```

AND

```
(function(){
  // code
})();
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions

Comment: The first one defines an anonymous function, the second one also executes it immediately after.

Comment: Given `f = function () { /* .. */ }`, it's the same difference as `f` vs `f()`; only the latter actually executes the function.